# Inline::java STUDY configuration

Tags: perl, inline, perl-module

The Inline docs aren't too helpful in learning how to use the STUDY config,
can anyone clarify the syntax involved in calling a simple void method that prints a method, say, Hello() ?

Also, in terms of the external java file, is there a specific directory i need to put it in, or does it go in the same directory of the perl script?

Comment: This is such a narrow subject (using Inline::Java to include Java code in an Perl script) that I'm afraid it could take awhile before you see an answer.  You may have better luck subscribing to and posting on inline@perl.org.  See http://lists.perl.org for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the file `/home/foo/java_src/Hello.java`, which contains:

```
public class Hello {
    public Hello() {}
    public void instance_hello() { System.out.println("hello world"); }
    public static void static_hello() { System.out.println("HELLO WORLD"); }
}
```

Tackling your second question first, the first argument after `use Inline Java ...` can be a filename, and so you can put your source file anywhere and refer to it by its file name in your perl code:

```
use Inline Java => '/home/foo/java_src/Hello.java';
$obj = Hello->new();
$obj->instance_hello();      # "hello world"
Hello->static_hello();       # "HELLO WORLD"
```

Note that you don't need `STUDY` so far. The `Hello` class is defined in source code that is read directly by the `Inline::Java` module, so the module automatically creates and populates the `Hello` namespace in Perl.

`STUDY` is for classes that aren't parsed directly by `Inline::Java`. So let's say instead that our `Hello` class has been compiled into a `jar` file called `/home/foo/jars/hello.jar`. Now to use the `Hello` class you would need to (1) include `hello.jar` in your `CLASSPATH` and (2) use `STUDY` to tell `Inline::Java` to create the `Hello` namespace:

```
use Inline Java => 'STUDY',
    CLASSPATH => '/home/foo/jars/hello.jar',
    STUDY => ['Hello'];
$obj = Hello->new;
Hello->static_hello;     # "HELLO WORLD"
$obj->instance_hello;    # "hello world"
```

We include the first argument `STUDY` to signal to the `Inline::Java` that we're not passing any source code directly to the module. We could have also passed valid source code or a valid source code filename.

```
use Inline Java => 'public class Nothing() { }',
    CLASSPATH => '/home/foo/jars/hello.jar',
    STUDY => ['Hello'];
```